# C# debugging: [DebuggerDisplay] or ToString()?

Tags: c#, debugging, tostring, debuggerdisplay

There are two ways to increase the usefulness of debugging information instead of seeing `{MyNamespace.MyProject.MyClass}` in the debugger.

These are the use of [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute) and the `ToString()` method.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...

[DebuggerDisplay("Name = {Name}")]
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
}
```

or

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name = {0}", Name);
    }
}
```

Is there any reason to prefer one to the other? Any reason not to do both? Is it purely personal preference?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Using `[DebuggerDisplay]` is meant only for the debugger.  Overriding ToString() has the "side effect" of changing the display at runtime.

This may or may not be a good thing.

Often, you want more info during debugging than your standard `ToString()` output, in which case you'd use both.

For example, in your case, the "ToString" implementation seems odd to me.  I would expect a "Person" class ToString() implementation to just return the Name directly, not "Name = PersonsName".  However, during debugging, I might want that extra information.

Comment: +1 To add on to Reed's "side effect" point: `ToString` is often used as a "default display string," e.g., by `Console.WriteLine` or WPF data binding.

Comment: Sure; the string's format was just given for a visual example to emphasize its similarity to the string given for DebuggerDisplay. The DebuggerDisplay format could as well return the name directly, as you say. I see your point about side effects though--it's the kind of distinction I'm looking for. I don't typically utilize the ToString method on classes much (except for the purpose I've given above) so its other usages weren't as apparent to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Slowness of the debugger can also be taken into account:

`DebuggerDisplayAttribute` format expression is **interpreted** by the debugger after each debugging step / breakpoint.

`ToString` is **compiled** in your code and is therefore much faster to execute by the debugger.

That's the same with conditional breakpoints: If the conditional expression is too slow to interpret by the debugger each time the execution reach the breakpoint, it can be useful to remove the breakpoint and instead add temporary code like this: `if (condition) Debugger.Break();`

Answer (score 8):

> "When you create a custom class or struct, you should override the
>   ToString method in order to provide information about your type to
>   client code."
>   — [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

If what `ToString()` returns and you see in debugger is not what you would like then you use `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

Personal Preference (when the desired output is not really 100% known)

1. Implement HelperFunction
2. Implement ToString in terms of HelperFunction
3. Implement DebuggerDisplay in terms of HelperFunction.

Now future edits can either differentiate or remain consistent as appropriate and there is better tracbility.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Xamarin to develop for Android, the ToString method will not be shown in the watch window, but DebuggerDisplay will.

Answer (score 1):

`DebuggerDisplay` is quicker to type for something simple.

`ToString()` can be much more complex in case the data you want to view depends on the properties of the object. Combine with `#if DEBUG` statement and you'll have a good DEBUG-only data viewer. Literally no one uses `ToString()` as-is for "client view", because it's too vague and any changes would be impossible to maintain logically. Everybody always call explicit properties or methods instead of `ToString()`, except if providing that string is the sole purpose of the class and it's the same also in debugging.

There also are the [DebuggerBrowsableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute?view=net-6.0) and [DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute?view=net-6.0), but those are just added complexity if there is no real need for such thing.

Answer (score 0):

`DebuggerDisplay` is quite limited in what it can do. You only have a format string that you can use to show values of certain members.

If you want to show data conditionally, data from several levels deep, or aggregated data, `ToString()` might be your only option.

Comment: I would say the capabilities are quite the same because you can point DebuggerDisplay to a calculated property. Thus you can easly return ToString() result or your own custom built string.

    [DebuggerDisplay("{" + nameof(DebuggerDisplay) + ",nq}")]
    public record Something<T>
    {
        private readonly string unique;

        public Something(string unique) { this.unique = unique; }

        private string DebuggerDisplay => this.ToString();

        public override string ToString() { return $"{typeof(T)}:{this.unique}"; }
    }