# ToString() on List<object> not working properly

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
Console.WriteLine("Distance to " + v.ToString() + ": " + v.minDistance);
List<Vertex> path = k.getShortestPathTo(v);
Console.WriteLine("Path: " + path.ToString());
```

v, is a Vertex, a class I have made, and prints fine. But path ends up outputting:

"Path: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Campus.Vertex]"

Campus being my project name. How do I get this to work? In Java, the equivelant output is: Path: [T13, Three, ETB].

Comment: If it's just for the purpose of debugging, there's the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute which is handy but in this instance it would require a specialisation of your List instance, upon which the attribute would exist. [c-sharp-debugging-debuggerdisplay-or-tostring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190987/c-sharp-debugging-debuggerdisplay-or-tostring)

Comment: Yes, it is just for debugging, Ill look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `.ToString()` does.  Unless it's overridden by a class, the default behavior on `object` is to simply return the name of the type.  Which is the behavior you're seeing.

If you want to print out the elements of your collection, then print the elements of the collection:

```
List<Vertex> path = k.getShortestPathTo(v);
foreach (var x in path)
    Console.WriteLine(x);  // Maybe include some other information in the output
```

Note that unless `Vertex` overrides `.ToString()` then you'll just see that same behavior.

Essentially you have two options:

1. Create classes which override `.ToString()` to return a meaningful string representation of their data/state.  Then call `.ToString()` on those objects.  In this case `Vertex` would need to override `.ToString()`, and also some custom containing class which holds a collection of `Vertex` objects would itself override `.ToString()`, and you'd use that containing class instead of a `List<Vertext>`.
2. Write procedural code which examines into the data/state of those objects and constructs output manually.

Answer (score 3):

Try using StringBuilder

```
List<Vertex> path = k.getShortestPathTo(v);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

foreach(Vertex v in path){
    str.append(v);
}

Console.WriteLine("Path: " + str.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

`path` is a type List<> which is a class, thus resulting `.ToString` to spit out Pointer to `path` and not the `Text` you want.

For this solution you will need to create a function that iterate the list and to `override` a method inside `Vertex` `ToString` class to return the formattion of `Vertex` object.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional way to combine the Vertex-elements, you can use the [`string.Join` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", path));
```

The first Argument is the separator between the items and the second argument is the list. `ToString()` is called for every item in the list to get the string-form.